# Can Angular client app receive http GET request with body?

Tags: angular

I have a web app in angular and I have my website. On my website, I have links to go to the angular app and I pass some data using the URL.

Example: **[www.myapp.com/user?example1=somedata&example2=111111](http://www.myapp.com/user?example1=somedata&example2=111111)**

I am wondering if it is possible to pass the URL params as DTO to my angular app.

Example:

```
{
   example: "somedata",
   example2: 11111,
}
```

Can Angular client app read incoming HTTP GET request with body?

Comment: not clear what you are trying to ask

Comment: The client, by definition, doesn't receive requests, it sends them. The server is what receives requests and "serves" the response. What are you trying to accomplish here? There is not enough information here to help you.

Comment: there's no such concept of "app being called from another site". apps get data from a server. the server that populates your app may be available to other apps, but the app itself is not available to other apps.

Comment: @Rick  I updated the description of the question.

Comment: You should avoid to use body on Get request. Is not Angular issue. Is how verbs should work in general.

Comment: I'm still unclear. apps don't "read incoming http get requests". app make "get requests" to a server and then read the response. and yes, angular apps can do that.

Comment: @Rick  Of course I know apps make "get requests" to a server and then read the response. I just had the doubt if it was possible to do what I was asking. Thank you very much for answering now I know it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly not. The GET request is done to the web hosting server (either the webpack development server or something with which you host the product of your build). It then returns your webapp to the client(browser).
By norm, according to the RFC2616 section 4.3 and sections 5.1.1 servers are supposed to discard the BODY, which means it will likely not get passed to your application once it is in the browser. Query params on the other hand are an element which can be read directly by angular core and router because they are part of the browser state.

You could host the application in a modified express server to accept body lines and do whatever you want with them but it would not be idiomatic, and I can't think of any purpose to it. Query can convey whatever POST BODY can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using HttpClient you'll need to use the request() method instead of get() if you're going to send data in the body of the get request.

```
  const httpRequest: HttpRequest<any> = {
   method: 'GET',
   body : {},
   url : 'www.url.com',
   headers : new HttpHeaders(),
  };
  this.httpClient.request(httpRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

hey man i hope you had obtain a solution, ive tried something like you, and say Nuno Sousa get requests not accept body, then what i did was make a post request to my server with Laravel API from AngularJS and receive some parameters in laravel, and this framework works with a different Standar like server course, after that make a get request with body and works from laravel, that makes sense to RFC2616 like says the partner. if you need help yet, send message.

Comment: Please reformat the text before posting it.